# HTML onclick - How to Access a Function

Tags: javascript, html, sockets, socket.io

I need to access a function that is within another function from a html onclick in a seperate file, I think because it's in another function this is why It's coming back as undefined, I can access functions that arent nested within my index file but the one I need I cant. The function is within my socket function as it uses its ID.

the function I am trying to access is in this format:

```
io.of('/main').on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('chat message', function (msg) {

     function oneCall() {
```

It is this oneCall functon I am trying to access. When I call a function that is out of this socket scope it works okay but I need the function within the socket?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to understand how function scope works. I would recommend you look up this topic. If a function only exists within another function, you cannot access it outside that scope. However, if the function is declared outside of the other functions scope, it's a simple `onclick` attribute with the name of the function you want to call. `<button onclick="nameOfFunction();">Click me!</button>`

Comment: I Understand Martin, Thanks. My trouble is that with the socket.io function it uses a socket.id so i can message the user. At the end of my oneCall function I emit to the user a message and use the socket ID, outside of this scope how can i pick up that ID?

Comment: You parse it as a parameter like you did initially on your `io.of`function. `oneCall(socketID)`.

Comment: Try to see if my answer down below made things more clear for you @Sparlarva

Comment: Curious as to what the update is on this. Did you get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look up *function scope*. If your function only exists within another function, then you cannot access that function outside of the other function's scope

Example:

```
function exampleFunction() {
    function otherFunction() {
        //do something
    }

    otherFunction();
}
```

From this very minimal example, we construct a function and call the function within another function. Now, if you try to call the *otherFunction* outside of the scope of *exampleFunction*, it will not work, because it's outside of the scope of *exampleFunction*. *otherFunction* only exists within the scope of *exampleFunction*.

Now, if you declared your function outside the scope of the other function, then you can access that anywhere on the page you like.

Example:

```
function exampleFunction() {    
    otherFunction();
}

function otherFunction() {
    //do something
}
```

The functions now work independantly, and otherFunction can be used anywhere you wish.
You can choose to call *otherFunction* inside *exampleFunction*, which will execute the *otherFunction* every time *exampleFunction* is called.

If you wish to use the *otherFunction* in an *onclick* functionality, then you can do that now, because it's independant, and exists within the *global scope*.

Example:

`<button onclick="otherFunction();">Click me!</button>`

In terms of your recent comment, about accessing specific values (a socket id in your case) in your function *oneCall*, you can choose to parse the value as a parameter for the function.

Example:

```
function oneCall(socketID) {
    //do something
}
```

The parameter *socketID* in the function *onceCall* now works as any JavaScript variable, and you can use it to do whatever logic you want.

And to parse the socket ID value to your function, you'd do something like this:

`onecall(variable_containing_socket_id);`

You can of course also declare more than one parameter in a function.

Example:

```
function oneCall(socketID, anotherParameter, andAnotherOne) {
    //do something
}
```

`onecall(socket_id, value, anotherValue);`

Simple information from W3Schools about function parameters [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_function_parameters.asp).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I've just started Work - on my break I will come back and read this, greatly appreciated.